# Fetch the users first_name ,city and number of rides taken during the current month

Tags: sql, oracle

**carpooling schema**
[image]

in order to display the name and city of users and number of rides they take during month December 2020.
i have tried following codes and got the table with rides counts but the answer obtained is not getting accepted.
please help me out.

```
SELECT u.first_name, u.city, COUNT(r1.ride_id)
  FROM user_details u, ride_users r1
 WHERE u.user_id = r1.user_id
   AND ride_id IN
       (SELECT ride_id FROM ride WHERE to_char(start_on, 'mm') = '12')
 GROUP BY u.first_name, u.city
 ORDER BY u.first_name, u.city;
```

Comment: *the answer obtained is not getting accepted* - you're asking us to do your coding challenge for you!?

Comment: The current month is January, by the way..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sql commands to fetch the users whose rides are maximum for month december](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65827793/sql-commands-to-fetch-the-users-whose-rides-are-maximum-for-month-december)

Answer (score 0):

Join the tables properly on their related columns and set the correct condition in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT u.first_name, 
       u.city, 
       COUNT(*) counter
FROM user_details u 
INNER JOIN ride_users ru ON ru.user_id = u.user_id
INNER JOIN ride r ON r.ride_id = ru.ride_id
WHERE TO_CHAR(r.start_on, 'yyyy-mm') = '2020-12'
GROUP BY u.first_name, u.city
ORDER BY u.first_name, u.city;
```

Comment: Recommend swapping that where clause predicate for a ranged effort

Answer (score 0):

If you want data from 2020-12, I would recommend:

```
SELECT u.first_name, u.city, COUNT(*) as counter
FROM user_details u JOIN
     ride_users ru
     ON ru.user_id = u.user_id JOIN
     ride r
     ON r.ride_id = ru.ride_id
WHERE r.start_on >= DATE '2020-12-01' AND
      r.start_on < DATE '2020-01-01'
GROUP BY u.first_name, u.city
ORDER BY u.first_name, u.city;
```

However the question asks about the *current* month and that has a habit of changing about 12 times a year.  For that, I would use this `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE r.start_on >= TRUNC(sysdate, 'MON') AND
      r.start_on < TRUNC(sysdate, 'MON') + INTERVAL '1' MONTH
```

Note:  I find that aggregating on the user's first name without the user id is suspicious, because it combines multiple users with the same name.  I suppose that is the intention of the query, which seems awkward to me.