# sql commands to fetch the users whose rides are maximum for month december

Tags: sql

[image]

I have to fetch the details of ride providers who have offered their ride most to users.

the `user_id` in `user_detail` table is same as `ride_provider_id` in `RIDE` table.

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Your question should include sample data and desired results and clarify what *you* mean by "most rides".  An attempt on your part is also appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following query should work :

```
SELECT TOP 10 
  CUD.USER_ID,
  CUD.EMAIL_ID,
  CUD.PASSWORD,
  CUD.FIRST_NAME,
  CUD.LAST_NAME,
  CUD.CITY,
  CUD.GENDER,
  CUD.PHONE_NO
FROM CARPOOLING.USER_DETAILS CUD
JOIN CARPOOLING.RIDE CR 
  ON CUD.USER_ID = CR.RIDE_PROVIDER_ID
GROUP BY 
  CUD.USER_ID,
  CUD.EMAIL_ID,
  CUD.PASSWORD,
  CUD.FIRST_NAME,
  CUD.LAST_NAME,
  CUD.CITY,
  CUD.GENDER,
  CUD.PHONE_NO
ORDER BY
  COUNT(*) DESC
```

However, I am not 100% sure it is the most efficient way to handle the problem. I would not mind feedback on the matter.

Comment: Please note that this is intended for SQL Server. Other SQL dialects could use a different keyword than "TOP" to limit the number of results.